# Disable mongodb NETWORK logs

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to disable NETWORK logs but can't find a way. As I can see in the docs, without using quiet I am already at the least verbose level with 0.

> The verbosity level can range from `0` to `5` :
>
> - `0` is the MongoDB’s default log verbosity level, to include Informationalmessages.
> - `1` to `5` increases the verbosity level to include Debug messages.

Is there a way to remove NETWORK logs but keep useful logs such as slow queries and the likes ?

Answer (score 0):

vi /etc/mongod.conf

```
systemLog:
  quiet: true
  path: /dev/null
```

Comment: OP asked how to retain other logs than NETWORK.